# What is the port Apple Screen Sharing listening?

Tags: remote-desktop

I am using Chicken of VNC and iSSH to access my home Mac mini with Screen Sharing enabled.
I can not sure which port the feature using,anyone could point it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HERE](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts1629) is a great table from Apple of all their most used ports.

Answer (score 7):

port 5900, standard for VNC

Comment: Also port 88 TCP for Screen Sharing authentication